# jQuery animation with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

HTML:

```
<div id="arrow" class="arrowhead"><div class="arrowline"></div></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    scroll();
});

function scroll() {

    var speed = "slow";
    var direction = "left";
    var options ={};
    options[direction] = 400;

    $( "#arrow" ).animate(options, speed )
                 .animate( options, speed, scroll );
}
```

I had this little animation of an arrow going left and right in a loop, but I wanted to make it more dynamic so I change the animation specifics.

Now the first animate works but the second doesnt?
And also I want the second animation to reverse?

Comment: Your animations [are doing the same thing (in a never-ending loop)](https://jsfiddle.net/uL7Lng0b/). You're passing the same `options` and `speed` values to both. Are you saying that the second animation should reverse the first one?

Comment: Well my first problem was that second animation wont work. Though I suppose it doesnt matter when I cant reverse arrows direction back, so I would loop perfectly @Stryner

Comment: animate is asynchronous,  so chaining them is probably not what you want to do.